While iterating through a loop, Logger.log repeatedly prints the same value
This Google Apps Script works correctly to save a number of Google docs in a folder as PDFs. However, the variable used to store the different file names--when printed with Logger.log--appears not to change. One of the files in the folder is (seemingly) arbitrarily chosen and printed over and over.
//https://github.com/Davor111/google-docs-to-pdf/blob/master/app.js

function gdocToPDF() {
  
  // Replace this ID
    var documentRootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("***redacted***") // replace this with the ID of the folder that contains the documents you want to convert

    Logger.log("Downloading " + documentRootFolder.getName() + "...");
    
    var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("***redacted***"); // replace this with the ID of the folder that the PDFs should be put in. 

    var documentRootFiles = documentRootFolder.getFiles()

    while(documentRootFiles.hasNext()) {
        createPDF(documentRootFiles.next().getId(), pdfFolder.getId(), function (fileID, folderID) {
            if (fileID) createPDFfile(fileID, folderID);
        })
    }
}


function createPDF(fileID, folderID, callback) {
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
    var templateName = templateFile.getName();
    
    var existingPDFs = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).getFiles();

    //in case no files exist
    if (!existingPDFs.hasNext()) {
        return callback(fileID, folderID);
    }

    for (; existingPDFs.hasNext();) {

        var existingPDFfile = existingPDFs.next();
        var existingPDFfileName = existingPDFfile.getName();
        if (existingPDFfileName == templateName + ".pdf") {
            Logger.log("PDF exists already. No PDF created")
            return callback();
        }
        if (!existingPDFs.hasNext()) {
            Logger.log(existingPDFfileName + " created")
            return callback(fileID, folderID)
        }
    }
}

function createPDFfile(fileID, folderID) {
    var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
    var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
    var theBlob = templateFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
    var newPDFFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
    newPDFFile.setName(templateFile.getName() + '.pdf');

}

What is it about iteration that I am not understanding?
Is there a best practices approach I should be using?

Shouldn't Logger.log(existingPDFfileName + " created") rather be Logger.log(templateName + ".pdf created")?

As you construct your for loop if the file already exists then this will be the response Logger.log("PDF exists already. No PDF created"). If it's not yet created then Logger.log(existingPDFfileName + " created")

Yes, the ".pdf" is missing from the log, not really important to the issue. The message "... No PDF created" is not logged. The script does what it is supposed to do, it is just that I can't get the Logger to work as expected.

Logger.log() Response
I tried your code and it's all working the problem I encountered is where the for loop if condition statements response in your logger.log().
for (; existingPDFs.hasNext();) {

    var existingPDFfile = existingPDFs.next();
    var existingPDFfileName = existingPDFfile.getName();
    if (existingPDFfileName == templateName + ".pdf") {
        Logger.log("PDF exists already. No PDF created");
        return callback();
    }
    if (!existingPDFs.hasNext()) {
        Logger.log(existingPDFfileName + " created");
        return callback(fileID, folderID)
    }
}

I change the response variable in your second if condition in your for loop.
From this:
Logger.log(existingPDFfileName + " created");

To this:
Logger.log(templateName + " created")

Whole Code:
function gdocToPDF() {

  // Replace this ID
  var documentRootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("***redacted***") // replace this with the ID of the folder that contains the documents you want to convert

  Logger.log("Downloading " + documentRootFolder.getName() + "...");


  var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("***redacted***"); // replace this with the ID of the folder that the PDFs should be put in. 

  var documentRootFiles = documentRootFolder.getFiles()

  while (documentRootFiles.hasNext()) {
    createPDF(documentRootFiles.next().getId(), pdfFolder.getId(), function (fileID, folderID) {
      if (fileID) createPDFfile(fileID, folderID);
    })
  }
}


function createPDF(fileID, folderID, callback) {
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  var templateName = templateFile.getName();
  console.log(templateName);


  var existingPDFs = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID).getFiles();

  //in case no files exist
  if (!existingPDFs.hasNext()) {
    return callback(fileID, folderID);
  } 

  for (; existingPDFs.hasNext();) {
    var existingPDFfile = existingPDFs.next();
    var existingPDFfileName = existingPDFfile.getName();
    if (existingPDFfileName == templateName + ".pdf") {
      Logger.log(templateName + " PDF exists already. No PDF created")
      return callback();
    } 
    if (!existingPDFs.hasNext()) {
          Logger.log(templateName + " created")
          return callback(fileID, folderID)
        }
      }
    }

function createPDFfile(fileID, folderID) {
  var templateFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileID);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderID);
  var theBlob = templateFile.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf');
  var newPDFFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);
  newPDFFile.setName(templateFile.getName() + '.pdf');

}


Sample Output
Sample Folders based on the script.
Before Execution



After Execution

This Output is based on the modified code.

Reference:

If Condition Statements
Console.log()


Thank-you. I asked a low-quality question.
